# Como usar mais de 1 classe dinamica com vuejs?

Tags: javascript, front-end, vue.js-2, vue.js

Bom dia/tarde / noite

Estou com uma duvida, tenho um projeto onde possuo uma classe dinâmica com operadores ternários, preciso adicionar outra classe dinâmica para trazer uma classe a mais nessa brincadeira toda, porem retorno sempre me da um erro de "syntaxe error" não consigo fazer ela funcionar pois não entendo como fazer o bind corretamente desse operador.

```
<div :class=" edit ? 'card-servico servico-valor servico-edit' : 'card-servico'" v-show="!tour || ei === 0">
```

EDIT:

A ideia é adicionar uma classe dinâmica nova, no caso sem interferir na operação que está sendo feita no edit.

```
data(){
 return {
   servicoPagante: {
      'pudim': true
    },
  }
}

<div v-on:click="edit ? :class=" edit ? 'card-servico servico-valor servico-edit' : 'card-servico', 'servicoPagante' :true " v-show="!tour || ei === 0">
```

porem adicionando ali o ServicoPagante, ele me da erro de sintaxe porque anterior a ele está rolando uma operação com ternário que está correta porem preciso **adicionar** mais essa classe para outra validação

Comment: Quais classes que vc que associar?

Comment: Queria usar dinamicamente essa servicoPagamento, porem ela nao rola por causa do ternario anterior que está rolando

Comment: Então vc tem 3 conjunto de classes: 1 - **card-servico servico-valor servico-edit**, 2 - **card-servico** e 3 - **servicoPagante**, vc quer fazer a condição para que seja qual? Tá bem confuso.

Comment: Tirando servicoPagante, as outras funcionam, quero fazer servivoPagante funcionar sem interferir nessas anteriores, ela seria a classe nova porem nao funciona devido ao ternario. Creio que nao estou sabendo adicionar ela sem interferir nas anteriores

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cria uma *computed property* que faça essa lógica. Na API do Vue podes retornar uma array com strings e objetos (parecido com o que estás a fazer no template), e ficaria assim:

No template:

```
<div :class="classesCardServico" v-show="!tour || ei === 0">
```

No componente ficaria:

```
computed: 
    classesCardServico(){

     return [
        'card-servico', 
        {'servico-valor': this.edit},
        {'servico-edit': this.edit},
        {'servicoPagante': this.servicoPagante.assinante }
      ];
    }
```

Comment: Editei meu comentario porque ficou muito confuso minha duvida, a operação ternaria vai rolar porem preciso adicionar mais 1 classe dinamica fazendo outra função sem interferir diretamente nessa opreção

Comment: @leonardosilva qual é a logica de `servicoPagante`? Só tem uma chave "pudim"? pode haver mais chaves? podes explicar melhor?

Comment: posso sim, vai haver 1 variavel onde dependendo de uma API retornar 1 valor true ou false vai adicionar 1 classe ou remover essa classe, no caso ServicoPagante, a ideia que a classe seja dinamica para o retorno da api falar se é valido ou não e se isso pode receber 1 estilo ou não

Comment: @leonardosilva então o valor que decide se a classe deve ser adicionada ou não é `this. servicoPagante.pudim`?

Comment: sim o pudim é só uma maneira deu ficar testando se a classe ta funcionando, seria algo como this.servicoPagante.free || this.servicoPagante.assinante

Comment: @leonardosilva e a classe só é acionada se `this.servicoPagante.assinante` for `true` ou também se `this.servicoPagante.free` for `true`? parecem-me mutuamente exclusivas...

Comment: a ideia é que por ele ser uma classe dinamica ele vai adicionar 1 classe e no css eu vou adicionar efeitos para o mesmo, se for free ele vai fazer X se for assinante vai fazer Y, o problema é que pela forma que foi colocado no :class="edti ? " ele fica chocando com essas classes e não queria que elas executassem juntas mas sim em paralelo sem afetar as mesmas, uma classe nova que eu coloco ali e faz outras coisas e nao influencia nas que já estão lá, porem tentei colocar com { } e me da erro de syntaxe e nao consigo isolar os ternarios

Comment: @leonardosilva eu percebo isso, isso é comum e simples. O que eu não percebo é a tua lógica, tens de explicar melhor... então em que condição queres adicionar a classe `servicoPagante`? quando `this.servicoPagante.assinante` for `true`?

Comment: Exatamente, quando eu receber de uma API e verificar se um elemento da API for verdadeiro eu vou trazer a condição TRUE para this.servicoPagante.assinante e o mesmo vai adicionar a classe até o meu elemento, se for falso adiciona OUTRA classe ao elemento

Comment: @leonardosilva ok, para esse caso específico de `this.servicoPagante.assinante` adicionar a classe `servicoPagante` caso seja `true` juntei agora à resposta. Depois é fazer o mesmo para outras classes da mesma maneira... as chaves desse objeto vão ser usadas como classes de o valor das mesmas chaves for `true`. Para ser mais consistente sugiro usares `servico-pagante` no nome da classe, assim manténs o estilo de nomenclatura que já tens nas outras.

Comment: Não entendi, como eu usaria, 1 methods, 1 data e 1 computed prop? não entendi ao certo como adicionar  e usar

Comment: @leonardosilva que método seria esse? não vejo nada sobre `methods` na pergunta... acho que parte do problema está ainda só na tua cabeça e não na pergunta ...

Comment: @leonardosilva podes dar uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/2rkLjzf0/6/ ? adapta para reproduzir o teu problema... tens nesse exemplo classes, methods, computed e data...

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, estou adptando a logica para ficar de mais facil entendimento, seu exemplo me ajudou bastante.